# How to convert text to lowercase and ignore spaces when using awk or grep temporarily?

Tags: linux, awk, grep, tr

I have 2 commands in my script as follows

```
awk -F'"(,")?' '
NR==FNR { r[$2] = $3; next }
{ for (n in r) gsub(n, r[n]) } 1' file2.csv file1.csv>xyzabc.csv
```

and

```
grep -v -f file3.txt xyzabc.csv>output.csv
```

so basically these commands compare files to produce a desired output.
My question is when comparing i want the comparison to be done in lower case and without spaces and also the removal of whitespaces and conversion to lowercase should be temporary i.e the original text should be printed in the output file. 
for example:

```
file1:         file 2.csv:
I AM A MAN     I am a man
I Like DoGs    i like DOGS
I like cats    I    like cats
```

so when using the commands mentioned above these strings are not equal.
I am trying to use tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' and tr -d [:space:] to do the job however I am struggling with the syntax. 
Also after the comparison is done i want to print it exactly the way as mentioned in file2.csv so this conversion into lowercase and removal of whitespace has to be temporary.
Thanks

edit:
I apologize for not being very clear with my samples.

so file1 contains the following data:

```
file1.csv:
I am a man
I like dogs
I am a doctor
I like cats
I drink coffee
```

and file2.csv contains the following data:

```
file2.csv:
I am a man,man
I like dogs,dogs
I drink coffee,I drink tea
```

I am using my awk command on these two files so what it does is it checks whether the the sentences present in the first column of file2.csv is present in file1.csv and replaces it with the contents in the second column of file2.csv and places the output in a different file.
so when doing the search i want it to be case insensitive and without spaces as file2.csv may contain multiple spaces between words or the case may be different.
Also,after the output is produced i do not want the contents of file1 and file2 to be altered.

As for the grep command command it is a simple find and delete command it looks for the same strings in both files and deletes them. I want this too to be compared without whitespaces as there may be multiple spaces present between words of wither files.

Comment: Please do mention the expected output in your post with code tags too and let us know.

Comment: Take a look at `grep -i` for case-insensitive matching

Comment: Yes i have already done that sorry i forgot to mention it in my question. 
I need the case insensitive part only for my first command.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    function asKey(str, tmp) {
        tmp = tolower(str)
        gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, " ", tmp)
        return tmp
    }
    NR==FNR {f2[asKey($0)]; next}
    asKey($0) in f2
' file2 file1
```

Given your sample files about, this returns all lines in file1.

I notice [mawk](/questions/tagged/mawk) does not collapse whitespace with that regex. You might want to replace `/[[:blank:]]+/` with `/[ \t\r]+/`